# object reference not set to an instance of an object scaffolding mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffolding

I have a problem to scaffolding my model.
I get following error "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

My model :

```
public class Position
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long PositionID { get; set; }
    public long OfferID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Positie omschrijving")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PositionNr { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double WorkingHeight { get; set; }        
    public long PalletTypeID { get; set; }        
    public long MotorTypeID { get; set; }        
    public long Enveriment { get; set; }   
}
```

My DBContext :

```
public class FlowContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

        //Positie
        modelBuilder.Entity<Position>()
            .HasKey(j => j.PositionID);
    }
}
```

My connection string in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FlowContext" connectionString="data source=.\SqlExpress; Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=Flow;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: In which action do you get error? How do you init your dbcontext ?

Comment: I get the error when I want to add controller to my MVC project, using MVC 5 Controller with views, using EF

Comment: would you take an screenshot of your error? it seem some vs related error.

Comment: Hi, I think I found the problem, if I build my project, my position class was build twice (why I don't know). I deleted my class and will start over again. My other classes I can scaffold also again, so I thinjk that was the problem.
A question can you have two dbcontext(to acces two different databases) in your MVC? Because that was the case in my project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when creating a new Web API controller with EF Scaffolding in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004392/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-when-creating-a-new-web-a)